# Need help on creating int range

Tags: c#, list, ftp, int

I want to make it where I input a name and then it applies a specified numerical range to the end of it.

Picture: [What the form looks like](http://i1071.photobucket.com/albums/u512/John_Dong/Untitled.png)

Input:

```
name(textBox1) - example: john_dong
Range(textBox2-textBox3) - example: 0-10
```

Output:

```
Name + Range (textBox4) - example:
john_dong0
john_dong1
john_dong2
john_dong3
john_dong4
john_dong5
john_dong6
john_dong7
john_dong8
john_dong9
john_dong10
```

It is definitely going to be using an int function.
I already have a save function working and a ftp upload function working I just have no idea where to start with the int.

Comment: the function has to be written in C# because the Forms application I am using/creating is in C#.

Comment: More details are definitely needed. How and when do you need this generated list? on the client side? Currently the wording of your question is vague.

Comment: I need it after I hit button1 ("Go") and I added a picture to help clear a few things up.

Answer (score 4):

Would [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) do?

```
var s = Enumerable.Range(0, 11).Select(i => "john_dong" + i).ToArray();
```

**Edit**: Updated per comment:

```
int min = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
int max = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
var s = Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1).Select(i => "john_dong" + i).ToArray();
```

**Edit**: Updated again per comment:

```
string name = textBox1.Text;
int min = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
int max = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
textBox4.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1).Select(i => name + i));
```

Comment: It should work let me take a look but the int range needs to be able to be specified using textBox1 (minimum value) and textBox2 (maximum value).

Comment: Here is a completed form just for an example:
[link](http://i1071.photobucket.com/albums/u512/John_Dong/Untitled-1.png)
But the textbox with all the names will be read only.

Comment: Perfect exactly what I wanted :) Thank you soooo much for the help I appreciate your time.

Comment: @John_Dong: You’re welcome! Don’t forget that the `int.Parse` calls may throw an exception if the user enters invalid data. You might want to handle this either by using `int.TryParse` instead, or through a `try/catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    var name = textBox1.Text;
    var lowerValue = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
    var upperValue = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

    if (upperValue < lowerValue) throw Exception(...);

    for (int i = lowerValue; i <= upperValue; i++)
         textBox4.Text += String.Format("{0}{1}\n", name, i);
} catch { ... }
```

Comment: That is for a console application isn't it? Because it contains console.writeline.

Comment: No, I just put that in there because I had no idea what you wanted to actually do with the values...

Comment: I wanted them printed into textBox4 which is a multiline textbox.

Comment: With each name on a seperate line.

Comment: @John_Dong: Fixed. That will do exactly what you want. It's wrapped in a `try-catch` because you might get invalid input in your text boxes.

Comment: It will do this right?: [link](http://i1071.photobucket.com/albums/u512/John_Dong/Untitled-1.png)

Comment: The biggest textbox (textBox4 - mulitline) will be read only.

Answer (score 1):

So, kind of like this?

```
var baseName = "john_doe";
var rangedNames = new List<string>();
foreach( var i in Enumerable.Range(a, b) )
{
    rangedNames.Add( baseName + i );
}
```